# expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[(long unsigned int)(n)]’

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

void convert(int *a1, int n, int *a2);

int main()
{

    int n;

    printf("Enter the length of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int a1[n];
    int a2[n];
    int i;

    printf("Enter the elements of the array: ");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++);
    {
       scanf("%d", (a1+i));
    }

    convert(&a1, n, &a2);

    printf("Output: ");

    for(i=0; i<n; i++);
    printf("%d ",*(a2+i));

    printf("\n");

    return 0;

}

void convert(int *a1, int n, int *a2)
{
    int *p;
    p = a1;
    while(p < a1+n)
    {
       *a2=(*a1+6)%10;
       a1++;
       a2++;
       p++;
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error message expected ‘int asterix’ but argument is of type ‘int (asterix)[(long unsigned int)(n)]’ for both &a1 and &a2. Not sure why it is doing this. The program is supposed to take the entered numbers in the array and take that number and plus 6 mod 10 and then out the converted number.

Comment: You don't need the address of `&` operator for arrays. They are automatically converted to poitners to their first element, equivalent to doing `&array[0]`.

Comment: Classic. For `int a[N]`, `&a` and `a` have different types.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a very common thing - that if you apply address of operator over an array will give you the pointer to the array.

The `&` when applied over an array it doesn't get converted to a pointer pointing to it;s first element. So what do we get?

`int a[10];`
`&a` will have type `int(*)[10]` meaning it is a pointer to an array of `int` containing 10 elements.

If your intention is to change the arrays when you pass it to other function just pass the array itself. It would get converted to pointer to the first element it conatains. By accessing the pointer you can make changes to it. So it serves the purpose.

In your case the call would be

```
 convert(a1, n, a2);
```

Here the array will be converted to pointer - type of which will be `int*`., which is different from `int (*)[]`. The compiler saw a mismatch and it complained.

---

The array decays into pointer to first element most of the cases. (Exceptions are when using it as an operand to `&`,`sizeof` etc).

---

Also your code in the function where it compares pointers - you are increasing both `p` and `a1` which is making you access positions that are beyond the array - which is undefined behavior (in your case that undefined behavior turns out to be segmentation fault). You should change that part of code like this:-

```
while(p < a1+n)
{
   *a2=(*p+6)%10;
   a2++;
   p++;
}
```

But even better you can do this to copy the whole thing

```
memcpy(a2,a1,n*sizeof(*a1));
```

or simply

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    a2[i]=a1[i];
```

Comment: Taking the '&' out took away the error, thank you. Now I'm getting a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

Comment: @AJP.: Check the answer.

Comment: Got rid of the error message again, thank you. Still having issues with the output though, I'm getting seemingly random numbers back. At least I'm getting something now :)

Comment: @AJP.: Wait you followed any of the solution provided in my answeR?

Comment: @AJP.: `for(i=0; i<n; i++);` There is a extra semicolon there. remove it in `main()`.

Comment: I used the while solution. I would normally use the for(int i =0;...) but for this program we're not allowed to use any loop variables other than pointers in the  convert function.

Comment: I saw that after I posted. The ; after the for in the main function is taken care of

Comment: @AJP.: If you use my solution then it wont give you error - because I ran your program and it is legal first of all. Check it and follow them.

Comment: Not getting any error messages anymore, just getting the expected output is all.

Comment: @AJP.: Whatever you have shown I have checked it. beyond it it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this!

```
 #include<stdio.h>

void convert(int *a1, int n, int *a2);

int main()
{

    int n;

    printf("Enter the length of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);


    int *a1 = new int[10];
    int *a2 = new int[10];
    int i;

    printf("Enter the elements of the array: ");
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++) //    for (i = 0; i<n; i++); the ";" is expected
    {
        scanf("%d", (a1 + i));
    }

    convert(a1, n, a2);

    printf("Output: ");

    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    printf("%d ", *(a2 + i));

    printf("\n");

    return 0;

}
void convert(int *a1, int n, int *a2)
{
    int *p;
    p = a1;
    while (p + n > a1 ) //this is true for loop on array
    {
        *a2 = ((*a1) + 6) % 10; //**a1 + 6 have fault 
        a1++;
        a2++;
        //p++;
    }
}
```

input/outputs:

```
Enter the length of the array: 5
Enter the elements of the array: 1
1
2
3
4
Output: 7 7 8 9 0
```